# All Files Access Permission Policy: Need to use Media Store API or No Access to Files

Tags: android

You have requested access to All Files Access permission but it appears that your app's core feature requires access to only Media Files or does not need access to any Files. In case your app needs access to Media Files, with the MediaStore API, apps can contribute and access media that's available on an external storage volume without the need for the access all files permission.
Please update your app so that the feature uses Media Store APIs and remove All Files Access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.